# Converting extension methods to instance methods with ReSharper?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

Suppose I have a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And an extension method:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Foo foo, int someNumber)
    {
        foo.Bar += someNumber;
    }
}
```

What would be the most convenient way to remove the `FooExtensions` class and alter `Foo` so it becomes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething(int someNumber)
    {
        Bar += someNumber;
    }
}
```

ReSharper doesn't seem to offer a one-step action to do this (strangely enough as this seems a pretty straightforward refactoring), but which other actions might I combine to avoid too much copy/pasting around and manual work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there *is* a ReSharper action for this, but it is named a bit awkwardly (imho). It's called "Make Method Non-Static".

The documentation can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings__Make_Method_Non-Static.html). Note that it doesn't mention extension methods specifically.

The same refactoring will work for other kinds of static methods (non-extension), which probably explains the naming.